# How to combine multiple SQL Queries without UNION or UNION ALL?

Tags: sql, oracle

There are 4 SELECT queries with JOIN consisting of different number of columns

- Table A1- 6 columns
- Table A2 - 11 columns
- Table A3 - 3 columns
- Table A4 - 3 columns

Sample sql query of mine:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Table A1 INNER JOIN table B ON B.fieldnaame = 'ABC' AND fieldname = 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Table A2 INNER JOIN table B ON B.fieldnaame = 'ABC' AND fieldname = 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Table A3 INNER JOIN table B ON B.fieldnaame = 'ABC' AND fieldname = 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Table A4 INNER JOIN table B ON B.fieldnaame = 'ABC' AND fieldname = 'A';
```

This above query is returning  error like this, ofcourse because there are mismatch in number of columns.

> ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns
> 01789. 00000 -  "query block has incorrect number of result columns"

Please let me know any ways to do without using UNION or UNION ALL.

Comment: Oracle errors come from Oracle.  I fixed the database tags.  The answer to your question is to select the columns you want, rather than `select *`.  That seems like a typo to me.

Comment: When you use UNION ALL, you have to have the same number of columns in all of your queries. Just use null or a substitute value for missing column data.

Comment: Perhaps you should be replacing the `*`'s with the columns you *actually* need. It's good practice to define them anyway.

Comment: In addition to other comments, knowing if there is a common "primary key" between the tables, what you may really need is a JOIN between them.  Since these tables are really small, I would strongly suggest listing the ACTUAL table structures to see actual column names for correlation between them.  Not asking for private data, just the structure.  As a newbie to S/O and trying to mask information can sometimes be more hurtful in getting the best answer for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write column names, if one of the tables does not contain any of field that the field exists on another table you can use custom columns.

Let's say that fieldC  does not exist on TableA4;

```
SELECT fieldA, fieldB, fieldC FROM Table A1 INNER JOIN table B ON B.fieldnaame = 'ABC' AND fieldname = 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT fieldA, fieldB, fieldC FROM Table A2 INNER JOIN table B ON B.fieldnaame = 'ABC' AND fieldname = 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT fieldA, fieldB, fieldC FROM Table A3 INNER JOIN table B ON B.fieldnaame = 'ABC' AND fieldname = 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT fieldA, fieldB, NULL as fieldC FROM Table A4 INNER JOIN table B ON B.fieldnaame = 'ABC' AND fieldname = 'A';
```

We can also rename fields, but in this case we must be very careful about type and data compatibility;

```
SELECT someFieldA as fieldA, someFieldB as fieldB, someFieldC as fieldC FROM Table A1 INNER JOIN table B ON B.fieldnaame = 'ABC' AND fieldname = 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT fieldA, fieldB, fieldC FROM Table A2 INNER JOIN table B ON B.fieldnaame = 'ABC' AND fieldname = 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT fieldA, fieldB, fieldC FROM Table A3 INNER JOIN table B ON B.fieldnaame = 'ABC' AND fieldname = 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT fieldA, fieldB, NULL as fieldC FROM Table A4 INNER JOIN table B ON B.fieldnaame = 'ABC' AND fieldname = 'A';
```

Comment: Thank you il try this way and let you know !!